# semantic ui dropdown items with images using remote data

Tags: javascript, dropdown, semantic-ui

I'm having trouble populating a dropdown

The code below works fine

```
<div class="ui multiple search selection dropdown" 
        style="width: 100%;" 
        id="list_id" >
    <input name="name" type="hidden">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">Lists</div>
    <div class="menu">
          <div class="item" data-value="{{value.value}}">
        <img class="ui avatar image" src="{{value.img}}">{{value.label}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but dont know how to do the same using remote data
I have already tried the apiSettings.onResponse etc methods but not sure what format to return the data in. I also confirmed using successTest that response is the same as I am retuning and onSuccess gets called too. But, nothing shows up in dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this is the way I solved it:

```
let dropdownValues = [];

types.forEach(type =>{ //populating dropdownValues
    let value = {};
    value.value = type;
    value.name = `<image class="ui mini image" src="/resources/${type}.png" />${type}`
    dropdownValues.push(value);
  })

$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    values: dropdownValues
})
```

As you can see it works like you intented: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MStzP.png)